Нужна помощь в цикле .after
Я делаю игру похожую на Civilization, и при создании у меня появилась проблема. Это связано с системой заработка и обновление информации специальном окне "о городе".
while_check_root_score()
while_money(5000)
def while_check_root_score():
    global lab_score_money_city
    global lab_score_civilisation_city
    global lab_score_income
    global money                 #Временно не работает P.S: При долгой игре он зависает
    lab_score_money_city.config(text = "Money:"+str(money))
    lab_score_civilisation_city.config(text="civilisation:"+str(civilisation)+" humans")
    lab_score_income.config(text="Income:"+str(income))
    root_score.after(2000,while_check_root_score)
    root_game.after(2000,while_check_root_score)
def while_money(cycle):
    global money
    money += income
    root_score.after(cycle,lambda: while_money(5000))
    root_game.after(cycle,lambda: while_money(5000))

Когда она запускается проходит пару секунд и зависает, это происходит от переполнении памяти я так думаю, а так я не знаю как его починить.
P.S: И да я использую tkinter как графический движок.

Так не делайте два раза after внутри while_money. У вас на каждый вызов количество вызовов удваивается и стремится к бесконечности.

Вообще не понятен смысл вот этих удвоенных after, зачем вы так делаете? Чтобы функция повторилась, ее один раз нужно передать в after.
